# Setting spaces in a path variable that is passed as a a function flag to MATLAB in Bash

Tags: bash, matlab, unix

I know there are several posts on how to include spaces in a path directory in bash. I think that this is a little different however since the fixes suggested in those posts have not worked for me.

My issue the following: I want to run a MATLAB script on a Unix cluster and maintain a log of what is going. MATLAB can be executed with a -logfile $file_name flag which tells it to store a log in a file specifed by the file_name variable. Unfortunately, I am running into problems because my file_name variable has spaces in it (due to a file structure that I cannot change).

With this said, here is a stripped down example of my code right now.

```
LOG_DIR="/Folder With Spaces/"   
LOG_FILE="File With Spaces.mat"  
matlab -r "script" -logfile ${LOG_DIR}${RESULT_FILE}.log
```

This works with LOG_DIR and LOG_FILE do not have quotes around them and do not contain spaces. When LOG_DIR or LOG_FILE do not have quotes but do have spaces, then MATLAB interprets file_name until the first space (i.e. it creates a log in /Folder). I have also tried to work with the "\" character but have not had much succes.

Any advice on how to get this working would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
matlab -r "script" -logfile "${LOG_DIR}${RESULT_FILE}.log"
```